# Arrange Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How can I sort the array ["Name":"OVERALL"] always last in the array element. This array ["Name":"OVERALL"] always on index 1. I think my current method is not a really good implementation. Is there any better ways?

```
[
  ["Name":"AHMAD SUFFIAN BIN AHMAD LOTFI","SLAData":[0,0,0,0,0,0],"RatingData":[0,0,0,0,0,0]],
  ["Name":"OVERALL","SLAData":[19,8,50,0,0,100],"RatingData":[95,95,100,0,0,0]],
  ["Name":"JAYALETCHUMI A\/P VENGADASALAM","SLAData":[33,14,100,0,0,0],"RatingData":[90,90,100,0,0,0]],
  ["Name":"MOHAMMAD FIRDHAUS BIN ISMAIL","SLAData":[0,0,0,0,0,0],"RatingData":[100,100,0,0,0,0]],
  ["Name":"YOGESWARAN A\/L PUSSAN","SLAData":[0,0,0,0,0,0],"RatingData":[0,0,0,0,0,0]],
  ["Name":"JAYAKUMAR PARAMASIVAM","SLAData":[0,0,0,0,0,100],"RatingData":[0,0,0,0,0,0]]
]
```

This is my current method

```
$Temp=[];
$output = array_slice($MonthlyData, 1, 1);
foreach ($MonthlyData as $data) {
    if($data['Name']!='OVERALL')
       $Temp[] = $data;
    }
}
$Temp[] = $output;
$MonthlyData = $Temp;
```

Comment: Is having that element of the array being last your only requirement? And is `$MonthlyData` always on that order?

Comment: yes. because this data is going to use with chartjs and I want the overall to show last in the label. The `$MonthlyData` may change according to the list of person but the Overall is always on the index 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's multiple ways to do this. I chose a way that doesn't require changing the code you provided much. All this code does is add the elements to a *front* of a temprary array unless it is the one you want to be last. That one it puts on the end of the array.

```
$MonthlyData = [
    ["Name" => "AHMAD SUFFIAN BIN AHMAD LOTFI","SLAData" => [0,0,0,0,0,0],"RatingData" => [0,0,0,0,0,0]],
    ["Name" => "OVERALL","SLAData" => [19,8,50,0,0,100],"RatingData" => [95,95,100,0,0,0]],
    ["Name" => "JAYALETCHUMI A\/P VENGADASALAM","SLAData" => [33,14,100,0,0,0],"RatingData" => [90,90,100,0,0,0]],
    ["Name" => "MOHAMMAD FIRDHAUS BIN ISMAIL","SLAData" => [0,0,0,0,0,0],"RatingData" => [100,100,0,0,0,0]],
    ["Name" => "YOGESWARAN A\/L PUSSAN","SLAData" => [0,0,0,0,0,0],"RatingData" => [0,0,0,0,0,0]],
    ["Name" => "JAYAKUMAR PARAMASIVAM","SLAData" => [0,0,0,0,0,100],"RatingData" => [0,0,0,0,0,0]]
];


$Temp=[];
foreach ($MonthlyData as $data) {
    if ($data['Name'] === 'OVERALL') {
        $Temp[] = $data;
    }
    else {
        array_unshift($Temp, $data);
    }
}
$MonthlyData = $Temp;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/G2EJf)

If you want a more concise way to do it, use [`usort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort based on a specified criteria. In this case, always put an array last if it's "name" value is "OVERALL".

```
usort($MonthlyData, static function ($a, $b) {
    return ($a['Name'] === 'OVERALL') ? 1 : -1;
});
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/h8k90)

Comment: Thanks. I like the `usort()` method.